# How do I put VLOOKUP in a cell and paste it down?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I'm using `VlookUp` in VBA, but it only works for one cell.

```
For Each MyCell In Selection
    MyCell = application.WorksheetFunction.VlookUp(Range("C2"), Range("A2:B50000"), 2 , 0)
Next
```

I want to set a `VlookUp` in a cell, then roll this to all other cells. But I am only able to put the formula in the first cell, then a double click to others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
With Selection
    .FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC3,R2C1:R50000C2,2,FALSE)"
    .Value = .Value '// Comment out if you don't want to paste values.
End With
```

This enters the `VLOOKUP()` formula into each cell using a relative reference for the lookup value's row and then effectively pastes values to replace the formula.

---

If you really want you can use VBA syntax:

```
For Each myCell In Selection
    myCell.Value = WorksheetFunction.Vlookup(Cells(myCell.Row, 3), Range("A2:B50000"), 2, False)
Next
```